is lucia library able to handle null values?
export async function createSessionCookie(userId: UserId, profileId?:string) {
  const session = await lucia.createSession(userId, {profile_id:profileId??null});
  const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);  return sessionCookie;
}

i am trying to create a session cookie that contains userId and profileId (sometimes profile id does not come in certain states ) so if do like this , will lucia be able to handle the null and will not throw an error ?
i am trying that ...
